# Swift UIkit Memory leak with UIViewController shared struct properties

Tags: swift, uikit

I am making an app in which there is a controller(1) from which other controllers are stored as properties, the controllers have a property called request that is used to know user information, and it is updated via the controller 1.

Controller 1 - request -> Controller 2

Controller 1 <- delegate - Controller 2

I declare the controllers as
"public private(set) lazy var " because while controller 1 is presented I want controller 2 to be saved so that it can be accessed at any time without having to call a new controller again, I want controller 2 to be saved and not be declare every time it is accessed because api calls are made inside controller 2 and 1 and I want that information to stay there until controller 1 is closed.

So basically what I want is that when controller 1 closes... controller 2 closes and both are popped out of the memory.

When I close controller 1 its deinit is called, but not on controller 2.

```
    class Controller1: UIViewController {
    
    deinit {
        //To avoid retained memory??
        controller1.request = nil
    }
    
    public private(set) lazy var controller1: Controller2 = { [weak self] in
        let controller = Controller2()
        controller.delegate = self
        return controller
    }()
    
    func update request(request: MemberRequest_Model?) {
        controller2.request = request
    }
}

extension Controller1: Controller2_Delegate {
    ///...
}


class Controller2: UIViewController {
    
    public var request: MemberRequest_Model? {
        didSet {
            setSections(with: request)
        }
    }
    
    weak var delegate: Controller2_Delegate?
    
    
    private func setSections(with request: MemberRequest_Model?) {
        //Update UI
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think your example is correct. E.g. `func update request(request:) {…}` is not syntactically correct. You also reference a `controller2` property that you are not showing us. We need a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I’m not seeing anything that would keep a strong reference to your `Controller2` instance. But we don’t have guess. Use [debug memory graph](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/gathering-information-about-memory-use) button and it will tell you where your lingering strong reference is. (You might need to turn on the “malloc stack” diagnostic if you want to see where that strong reference was established.)

Comment: If you forgive me for saying it, you really should never have to keep a view controller around for the sake of its model data or API responses. It suggests a deeper problem. But I’d suggest fixing your strong reference cycle problem, first. Hopefully the debug memory graph will help you find where your lingering strong reference is.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, how would you declare a controller inside another controller?

Comment: You don’t have view controllers inside view controllers, so the question doesn’t make sense. View controllers represent the views that are present in the UI. When views are dismissed, so are the associated view controllers.